# Insert Item at index in sorted array

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swift3

I want to insert an item at an index in a sorted array. Should I be using binary search or is the below implementation good?

This below implementation does not work but the concept is clear. For some reason it gives me an error: "Value 'Double' has no member 0" but when I get rid of the `&& $1.0 > price` it runs but doesn't do what I want. How would I insert a value in an array between two values using the method below or any better method?

It would be an added bonus if I could update the second (quantity) value if price was already there in the array. For example if in the original array the value is (20,5) where price is 20, I would want to update that index to be (20,9).

The array is an array of Doubles that represent a price and a quantity for that price. I cannot use a dict because it needs to remain in order.

I will have more than 10K items in the array.

Here is my code.

```
let largeArray = [(10, 3), (20, 5), (30, 6), (40, 1), (50, 3), (60, 3)]
let price = 45 
if let indexInsert = largeArray.index(where: {$0.0 < price && $1.0 > price}) { 
     self.sellSideOrderBook.insert(((45, 2)), at: indexInsert)
}
```

Comment: Your code compiles with `{ $0 < price && $1 > price }`, but that  would be slower than a binary search.

Comment: it does not compile with  { $0 < price && $1 > price }. It gives me the error mentioned above

Comment: That is strange, I tried it and it compiled for me (Xcode 8.3.3).

Comment: `{ $0 < price && $1 > price }` is wrong anyway, it does not compare with two adjacent array elements.

Comment: Is there a way to do it using this method?

Comment: Sure: `let indexInsert = largeArray.insertionIndexOf(elem: (45, 2), isOrderedBefore: { $0.0 < $1.0 })`